# Supporting accounts in a ContentProvider

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, android-syncadapter

I am trying to enhance my app to support multiple and [accounts](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/accounts/Account.html) using my own [AccountAuthenticator](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/accounts/AccountManager.html), the AccountManger, and a custom [Account Type](https://developer.android.com/training/id-auth/custom_auth.html).  I understand how to build a SyncAdapter and a ContentProvider.  (I learned from the [Android reference pages](https://developer.android.com/training/sync-adapters/index.html))

**But I am confused about how to tie an account to a content provider.**

In the SyncAdapter, the function `onPerformSync()` passes a reference to the Account object that triggered the sync adapter.  That works fine.  But once inside, what do I do with this information?

```
@Override
public void onPerformSync(
    Account account,
    Bundle extras,
    String authority,
    ContentProviderClient provider,
    SyncResult syncResult) {

    Log.d(TAG, "onPerformSync");

    // account??

    Cursor c = provider.query("content://org.example.myapp/letters", DataContract.Letters.PROJECTION_ALL, selectionClause, selectionArgs, DataContract.Letters.SORT_ORDER_DEFAULT )
}
```

ContentProviders do not seem to support an Account object directly.  It seems that we have to support it ourselves by adding an account property to every insert, update, delete and query.

Something like this:

```
content://org.example.myapp/letters/d0470cc1c6af4b7bab8e8cedd58d2329/123
```

**Where**: the first UUID is the account id and the trailing integer is the record number

**This also means that we have to manually take care of house-keeping code when someone deletes an account from the AccountManager.** This is probably the most troubling part.

I find this strange.  After all the reading that I've done on Content Providers and Sync Adapters, you'd think that someone else would have thought to explain how to do this.  This is what prompted me to ask that here.

Is there some elegant way to support accounts, use content providers and syncadapters and not have to lace every insert, update, delete and query with an extra account variable?

One of the advantages of having an account type is that it can clean up sync adapter settings when the user add/removes accounts.  But what about cleaning up the contents for that account inside the content provider?  I'm not sure if this housekeeping can be done somehow through the AccountManager?